Is this a harmful insect?
I found this insect crawling on my neck while standing under a tree. I am wondering if it's a harmful (to humans) insect. I live in Prague. It is small (not even a centi-meter I think).

Harmful to what? All insects eat something. But it seems unlikely to be harmful to humans.

Seems like a species of true bug. Some, like bed bugs or assassin bugs are harmful, but this one doesn't particularly resemble any of those.
